# C++, Pointer to an object resets values of string variables

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is a function getValue(string name) from the Map class that I am using in my program
The Map class stores strings as key and the ValueType as values.

```
template <typename ValueType>
  ValueType Map<ValueType>::getValue(string key)
    {
        if (containsKey(key))
            return (*this)[key];
        Error("Attempt to getValue for key which is not contained in map.");
        return ValueType(); // this code is never reached, but here to placate compiler
    }
```

In graph.h file I am using the Map to store nodes (node class implementation below) mapped by there names.

The graph.h file

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include "node.h"
#include "map.h"

class Graph{
public :
    Graph();
    ~Graph();
    void addNode(string name, double x, double y);
    Node* getNode(string name);

private :
    Map<Node> nodes;

};

Graph::Graph(){}

Graph::~Graph(){}

void Graph::addNode(string name, double x, double y){
    if(!nodes.containsKey(name)){
        Node n(name, x, y);
        nodes.add(name, n);
    }
}

Node* Graph::getNode(string name){
    if(nodes.containsKey(name)){
        return (&nodes.getValue(name));
    }else{
        Error ("No node with that name exists");
    }
}

#endif
```

The Node Class

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node{

public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    Node(string nodename, double nodeX, double nodeY);
    void toString();
private:
    string name;
    double x,y;

};

Node::Node(){}

Node::~Node(){}

Node::Node(string nodename, double nodeX, double nodeY){
    name = nodename;
    x = nodeX;
    y = nodeY;
}

void Node::toString(){
    cout<<"Name "<<name<<", Location "<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
}


#endif
```

I am trying to create a pointer to the Node Object that is being retrieved from the Map
But the returning pointer sets the value of the `string name`
 varaible to blank.

In the main.cpp file

```
Graph g;
g.addNode("0COOL",42,42);
Node *n = g.getNode("0COOL");
n->toString();
```

The Output of the above code comes out to be

> Name , Location 42, 42

Why is the name field being omitted?

Comment: is there a reason why you put your definitions into the headers?

Comment: temporary/local object getting destroyed after function scope...

Comment: An off-topic note: The name of the function `toString` is confusing. This name implies that a string representation *is returned*, not *printed*. I'm suggesting these names: `print`, `debug` or `dump`, and I'm also suggesting to put the output stream as an argument, defaulting to `std::cout` if you like, but giving the user the option to dump somewhere else. Or you write it as an `operator<<` to make it consistent with how you print stuff in the standard library: `cout << *n` instead of `n->print(cout)`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Map<ValueType>::getValue(string key)` returns the result by value. When you do this

```
return (&nodes.getValue(name));
```

you are returning a pointer to a temporary variable created by the compiler to store the result of `getValue`. Dereferencing this pointer later is undefined behavior, because the object pointed to by the temporary gets destroyed upon exiting the `Graph::getNode(string name)` function.

To fix this problem, return `ValueType` from `Map<ValueType>::getValue(string key)` by reference. This would limit the lifetime of the pointer to the lifetime of the corresponding element in the map. Of course you need to make sure that there is a valid reference to return in all cases - specifically, this would not be legal: `return ValueType()`. You would need to create a static variable to represent the missing value, and return a reference to it when the value is not found.